# i am confused with the child process that I have to implement for each unix command in this program

Tags: c, unix, arguments, computer-science, child-process

I just want implementation of child process for each unix command that I have created and need to printout each process id. It should be like for every individual unix command I have to make child process

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    if(argc == 1){
        printf("Pass UNIX commands as command line arguments to execute it.");
        exit(0);
    }
    
    int commandLen = ceil((argc - 1)/2) ;
    printf("Command length : %d", commandLen);
    pid_t pids[commandLen];
    
    for(int i=1; i< argc ; i= i +2 ){

              if( i< argc && (i+1)< argc){
                    char * command = (char *) malloc(2 + strlen(argv[i])+ strlen(argv[i+1]) );
                    strcpy(command, argv[i]);
                    strcat(command, " ");
                    strcat(command, argv[i+1]);
                    system(command);
                }else{
                    system(argv[i]);
                }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the system function doesn't provide any mechanism to return process IDs for childs.

Comment: The `system()` function runs a process for you — you don't need explicit `fork()` calls when you use `system()`.

Comment: You're right I didn't note the system function there. So must edit.